# php http request illegal offset

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a php script which allows http requests to insert certain data into a database. I have 3 files for this:

***Database.php***

```
<?php
class Database{

    private $host = "******";
    private $db_name = "*********";
    private $username = "**********";
    private $password = "**********";
    public $conn;

    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

***Record.php***

```
<?php
class record{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "data";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $Naam;
    public $Eindtijd;
    public $Tijdstip;

    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    function create(){

    // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                Naam=:Naam, Eindtijd=:Eindtijd, Tijdstip=:Tijdstip";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->Naam=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Naam));
    $this->Eindtijd=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Eindtijd));
    $this->Tijdstip=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->Tijdstip));

    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":Naam", $this->Naam);
    $stmt->bindParam(":Eindtijd", $this->Eindtijd);
    $stmt->bindParam(":Tijdstip", $this->Tijdstip);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>
```

And ***Test.php***

```
    <?php

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
// get database connection
include_once 'database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once 'record.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new record($db);

// get posted data
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.kevinit.nl/school/fontyskart/php/test.php");

// set product property values
$product->Naam= $data['Naam'];
$product->Eindtijd = $data['Eindtijd'];
$product->Tijdstip = $data['Tijdstip'];
// create the product
if($product->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo json_encode(['message' => 'Product was created']);
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo json_encode(['message' => 'Unable to create product']);
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

I tried to sent the following request:

https://www.kevinit.nl/school/fontyskart/php/test.php?Naam=Lala&Eindtijd=lala&Tijdstip=lala

This got me the following error message:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Naam' in
>   /mnt/web106/b1/74/58274074/htdocs/school/fontyskart/php/test.php on
>   line 25 Warning: Illegal string offset 'Eindtijd' in
>   /mnt/web106/b1/74/58274074/htdocs/school/fontyskart/php/test.php on
>   line 26 Warning: Illegal string offset 'Tijdstip' in
>   /mnt/web106/b1/74/58274074/htdocs/school/fontyskart/php/test.php on
>   line 27 {{"message":"Product was created"}}

As you can see: it does create a product in the database, but they are just empty records

Since I'm pretty new at PHP I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: file_get_contents does not get the posted data. Read the docs for that function. I have no idea where you got the notion that it would do what you're expecting. You won't find any examples of it online, tutorials, nothing in the documentation which could give you that impression. What made you decide to try that?? It will make a fresh HTTP request and get whatever the response is sent back from calling that URL, as text, not an array. what you want to be doing to fetch the data posted to your script is to be reading from the $_POST array. Every PHP tutorial in the world will show you that.